# Visual Studio : compile list of modules on each platform and configuration

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, compilation, automation

I am working on a huge `C++` project, targeting many platforms with several configurations for each platform.

Because of the long compilation time, build the entire project on every platform to test if a change compile successfully, isn't an option.

What I usually do, is compile the single cpp modules I modified on different combination of platform/configuration.
I'd like to automate this process, either using a script, a VS extension, whatever, I am open to evaluate different options.

What I need exactly is taking a list of cpp files and compile each file, for each platform and each configuration (basically iterating through all combination of the configuration manager).

Is this possible? any good suggestion on how to approach the problem?

---

EDIT:

I am aware that this is way far to be a perfect solution, and will spot only a subset of errors.
I will still have to face linking errors, compiler errors on other cpp units depended on a modified header, and so on..

I also, don't have any chance to modify the current build system, or project generation.

I am mostly interested in a local solution, to reduce the amount of possible issues and facing the huge building time process.

---

EDIT2

We have a build system. This has to be considered a pre-build system optimization, for my personal workflow.

Reasons:

Triggering a build system job requires time. It will be the final step, but instead of spending hours waiting, and maybe discover later that a given compiler on a given platform for a specific configuration raise an error, it would be much more efficient to anticipate those findings as much as possible.

Current manual workflow:

1. Open each cpp file I modified
2. Compile each cpp file as a single unit (not building the project. On VS Build-> Compile)
3. Change Platform and/or configuration and re-do point 2 again.

This is the manual workflow I'd like to optimize.

Comment: Are you using Content Integration tools to automatically build when code changes are made?

Comment: No. There is a complex build process, but this is irrelevant to my question. What I need is to compile the single units.

Comment: Curious the "too broad" flag. The question is quite specific.

Comment: I think tools like ccache(https://ccache.samba.org/) might help here.

Comment: Too broad might mean that you don't provide enough specifics on your exact workflow. Seems like you're already doing something to solve your problem; you could describe it in greater detail, maybe with an example. It sounds like you could create a VS extension or try to record a macro based on what you're currently doing and expand it to generalize it.

My understanding is that you get the latest changes from a repo, then click through all platforms and all configurations and hit compile one by one and publish the error messages all manually. Is this correct?

Comment: @gyuri: Let's say I have local changes I want to submit. 1) I open all modified cpp files. 2) compile each as a single unit (CTRL + F7) 3) repeat to for all configurations (es. arm vs x64, debug vs release). I want to automate this process.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you "simply" write a script to do this (using Python for instance, which is very powerful for this kind of this)

You could:

- Parse the .sln file to extract the list of configurations, platforms (    `GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms)` entry) and projects (`Project` entry)
- If needed, you can parse every project to find the list of source files (that's easier than parsing the .sln, as vcxproj files are in xml). Look for `ClCompile` xml nodes to extract the list of .cpp files.
- Then you can identify which projects needs some files to be recompiled (getting list of modified files as script input parameter or based on timestamp checking)

Finally, to rebuild, you have two options:

- Call "msbuild " to recompile the whole project (vcxproj) (for instance         `msbuild project.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug;TargetFrameworkVersion=v3.5`)
- You could also recompile a single file (`cl simple.cpp`). To do so, you need to know what are the `cl` build options to be sure you compile the file exactly the same way as Visual Studio would. If you earlier did a full build of the solution (it could be a rquirement for your script to work), then you should be able to find that from Visual Studio logs (within the target folder). In my solutions, I can find for every project (vcxproj file) a build log per configuration (in `%OUTPUT_DIR%\lib\%libname%\%libname%.dir\%configuration%\%libname%.tlog\CL.command.1.tlog`), this file reports the exact `cl` arguments that were used to compile every file of the project. Then you can manually invoke `cl` command and this should end up recompiling the file the same way Visual Studio would do it.

Additionnaly, you could add a project in your Visual Studio solution that would fire this script as a custom command.

Such a script should be able to identify which projects has to be rebuilt and rebuild them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked the documentation of msbuild. My issue is, I can't trigger a full build for every platform (this is mostly the point of the question) because long build time. I am forced to compile the single cpp units, and yes like you can imagine I'd like to avoid to extract all the cl parameters.

Comment: @Heisenbug You should mention the metrics of your solution. How many projects? How many files per project? Basically, if you have hundreds of projects, building only a few projects rather than the whole solution will save less time than building only a few files but may not be a bad solution.

Comment: Also, are you by chance creating your solution through CMake?

Comment: trust me. even building projects it's a no go. I have no control how solutions/project are generated. Because of what I manually do is changing configuration and pressing ctrl+F7 that triggers the compilation of the current open cpp unit, I am just looking for a way to automate that.

Comment: @Heisenbug: Edited my post with a method that makes it possible to find the exact `cl` arguments to be used to manually recompile a file.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *very* common requirement, it is never solved this way.  What you are proposing is not completely impossible, but it is certainly very painful to implement.  You are overlooking what should happen when you modify a .h file, that can force a bunch of .cpp files to be recompiled.  And you are not considering linker errors.  While you'll have a shot at discovering .cpp files, discovering #include file dependencies is very gritty.  You can't get them from the project or make file.  Compiling with /showIncludes and parsing the build trace files is what it takes.  Nothing off-the-shelf afaik.

Don't do this, you'll regret it.  Use the solution that everybody uses: you need a build server.  Preferably with a continuous integration feature so the server kicks-off the build for all target platforms as soon as you check-in a code change.  Many to choose from, [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145586/what-continuous-integration-tool-is-best-for-a-c-project) talks about it.

Comment: I am perfectly aware that is not a perfect solution. I won't get linker errors and errors in different cpp units including modified headers and so on.. Still, this is quite helpful to quickly find some common mistake: 1) difference between compilers eg. signed vs unsigned comparison errors/warnings on different compilers 2) lines of code excluded by compilation by preprocessing macro and so on.

Comment: Sounds like you think that a build server cannot do this.  Or that it somehow sucks at doing this.  That is not accurate.  Hard to convince somebody when they are locked-in on a solution, I gave it a shot.

Comment: I can't modify the building mechanism nor installing a build server. It's not that I don't want, or don't consider it. It's simply something out of my control.

Comment: Show this Q+A to your supervisor.

Comment: To be precise: we have a build server already doing that job. This question is to implement an early check, in order to reduce the amount of possible issues before submitting changes that triggers a re-build on all platforms in the build server. This will save time in the end, if I can catch a minor compiler error way without involving the build server itself.